# BackPressure or Control Rate Nifi processor for large quantity of files

Tags: apache-nifi, sftp

I have a `ListSFTP` processor that is pulling over `600,000` files every **15 mins** and it is causing bottlenecks in the flow. The files are small, **50kb** max.  I have tried to use a control rate processor and also increasing the backpressure threshold but nothing seems to help move the files through the queue. Please help :)

The Control Rate processor is set to flowfile count set to `50,000` max. The backpressure I have increased from `10,000` to `100,000` `500,000` and up to `1,000,000` but I am still seeing bottlenecks.

Comment: Could you please help us with the flow [image], showing where you see the bottleneck and the properties being set in the ListSFTP and the place you see the flowfiles are getting stuck

Comment: Which processor/logic is causing the bottleneck? Once you list the files from FTP then what is downstream logic?

Comment: Can you use MergeContent or MergeRecord to create larger files to send downstream?